# Roundcube - set recipient in GET parameter

Tags: hyperlink, roundcube

I'm trying to prepare a link to the Roundcube mailer hosted on my server, that would include recepient email address - is it possible?

I've been trying for some time, digging through the docs and even through the Roundcube's source code but no luck.

For clarification, I'd love to be able to have something like:
http://webmail.myserver.tld/?_task=mail&_action=compose&_SOME_PARAM_NAME=xxx@xxx.xx
that would redirect an user (we can safely assume he is already logged in) to a "new message" form with a "To:" field filled with xxx@xxx.pl

I've tried some different (obvious) names for "SOME_PARAM_NAME" (recipient, to, receiver, mailto, etc.) but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it by looking here:

http://vanappdeveloper.com/2012/07/30/roundcube-integration-with-an-iframe-in-a-3rd-party-cms-custom-attachments/

In your plugin you would reference SOME_PARAM_NAME like so:

```
$args['param']['SOME_PARAM_NAME']
```

To set the 'to' address you would:

```
$params['param']['to'] = $args['param']['SOME_PARAM_NAME'];
```

You can do the same with body,cc,subject and bcc instead of 'to'

Don't forget to `return $params;` at the end of the hook.